# Sqlite NOT IN unexpected behaviour

Tags: sqlite

Let's say I have two tables both with one column "col".
Table `A` with values `A,B,C,D,E`
Table `B` with values `H,I,J,K,NULL`.

Now, when I run the query `SELECT col from A where col NOT IN (SELECT col from B);` I get an empty result.
Obviously it only happens when `NULL` is one of the values returning from the inner query.
Is there a logic behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cannot u try this ?

```
SELECT col from A where col NOT IN (SELECT col from B where col is not null);
```

Usually null has specific behavior, what is happening is that the query is unable to compare the values against null, so it is ignoring the other results.usually this have to be changed in the database options –

Comment: Usually null has specific behavior, what is happening is that the query is unable to compare the values against null, so it is ignoring the other results.usually this have to be changed in the database options

Comment: Thanks! I hope I will remember that in the future

Comment: Welcome, I have updated the answer, so please if that what you want, just marked as answered....Enjoy programming!

Answer (score 1):

From: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_null_values.htm

> The NULL value can cause problems when selecting data, however,
>   because when comparing an unknown value to any other value, the result
>   is always unknown and not included in the final results.